# libvirt/virsh unable to destroy vm

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization, kvm, libvirt

I have a big problem with my kvm:
I wanted to shut down my machine "Owncloud", after the power state of "Owncloud" is "in shutdown".
When I try to destroy this machine with "virsh destroy Owncloud" I got the following:

> error: Failed to destroy domain Owncloud!
>   error: An error occured, but the cause is unknown

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 for virtualization.

What can I do to destroy the machine without restarting the host system?

Comment: Checkout the qemu log from `/var/log/libvirt/qemu/Owncloud.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always kill qemu process directly, but libvirt log should provide better information on what exactly went wrong.